# Remove binding not working when using bindingbase.Clearbinding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

I have been trying to remove the binding for my text box. I have used a multbinding converter to set the text of textbox which takes the text for data context and textbox as the input to converter. 
Ongotfocus of the text box I remove the binding of the textproperty of the text. However, the binding is not getting removed.

```
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{Converter.Instance}">
                            <Binding Path="Value" Mode="OneWay" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"/>
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBox.Text>

    private void OnPatientTextBoxGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBoxObj = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBoxObj != null && textBoxObj.DataContext != null && textBoxObj is DependencyObject textBox && textBoxObj.DataContext is StringAttribute dataContext)
        {
            SetKeyboardFocus(textBoxObj);
            _bindingBase = BindingOperations.GetBindingBase(textBoxObj, TextBox.TextProperty);
            textBoxObj.Text = dataContext.Value;

            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(textBox, TextBox.TextProperty);}}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. `BindingOperations.ClearBinding` does clear the binding.

Comment: It does clear the value when we use value directly instead of multibinding converter. However, after adding the converter, binding is not getting cleared.